How to reverse engineer a specific QR code?
I'm working on a project where I need to generate an exact replica of a specific QR code. I have detailed information about the QR code, including its version, error correction level, mask pattern, data blocks, and the final decoded string. However, I'm unsure about the process to recreate it precisely.

Here are the details of the QR code:

Version: 3 (29x29)
Error Correction Level: L
Mask Pattern: 0
Data Blocks:
[
  "01000001","11010110","10000111","01000111","01000111","00000111","00110011",
  "10100010","11110010","11110111","01110111","01110111","01110010","11100111",
  "00000110","00010111","00100110","01100110","11110110","10010111","00110010",
  "11100110","00110110","11110110","11010010","11110111","01100110","10010110",
  "01010111","01110010","11110001","00000001","10001110","00001010","00011001",
  "00000001","00010111","11010000","10010011","10010011","01000000","11101100",
  "00010001","11101100","00010001","11101100","00010001","11101100","00010001",
  "11101100","00010001","11101100","00010001","01001001","10101010","11011101",
  "10000010","11101011","10110110","00101100","01011001","11110111","00111111",
  "10011000","11011010","01000001","11001100","01000111"
]


Final Data Bits:
01000001110101101000011101000111010001110000011100110011101000101111001011110111011101110111011101110010111001110000011000010111001001100110011011110110100101110011001011100110001101101111011011010010111101110110011010010110010101110111001011110001000000011000111000001010000110010000000100010111110100001001001110010011010000001110110000010001111011000001000111101100000100011110110000010001111011000001000111101100000100011110110000010001


Decoded Data Segments:

https://www.parfois.com/view/
224646
_BNM


Final Decoded String:
https://www.parfois.com/view/224646_BNM



I'm trying to generate a QR code in Python that matches specific requirements:

Version: 3 (which is a 29x29 size QR code)
Error Correction Level: L (Low)
Mask Pattern: 0
Data to encode:

Segment 1: URL "https://www.parfois.com/view/" (Byte mode)
Segment 2: Number "224646" (Numeric mode)
Segment 3: Suffix "_BNM" (Byte mode)



Here's what I've tried so far:
1. qrcode library
I found that qrcode doesn't seem to provide enough control over the QR version, error correction level, and mask pattern. It also doesn't offer straightforward ways to specify encoding modes for different data segments (numeric vs byte).
2. qrcodegen library
This seemed like a better fit, but I hit some issues when trying to lock the version and mask pattern. Here's an example of what I tried:
qr = QrCode.encode_segments(
    segments,
    ecl=QrCode.Ecc.LOW,  # Error correction level L
    version=3,           # Fix the version to 3
    mask=0,              # Mask pattern 0
    boost_ecl=False      # No automatic error correction boosting
)

But this threw an error:

TypeError: QrCode.encode_segments() got an unexpected keyword argument 'version'

So it looks like qrcodegen doesn't allow you to fix the version or set a specific mask pattern using this method (at least in my environment).
3. segno library
I also gave segno a shot since it supports QR code generation and seemed flexible. However, I'm still not sure how to fully control things like mask patterns and data segmentation as needed.
What I need help with
How do I generate a QR code with these specific requirements (version, error correction level, mask pattern, and data segmentation)? Ideally, I'd like to know which Python library is best suited for this, and how to set it up.

you don't need the entire roundtrip. you just need to copy every module ("pixel") of the reference code. libraries should be able to give you the "ideal image" of any scanned code. or you do it by hand. "an exact replica" is a terrible specification. you already have the code, so you're done without doing anything.

Here is some demo code which generates the QR code to your specifications and decodes to your final decoded string.
import qrcodegen
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

# Function to generate the QR code image
def generate_qr_image(qr: qrcodegen.QrCode, scale: int = 10, border: int = 4):
    size = (qr.get_size() + border * 2) * scale  # Calculate image size based on QR size and border
    img = Image.new("1", (size, size), 1)  # Create a white image
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

    # Draw the QR code
    for y in range(qr.get_size()):
        for x in range(qr.get_size()):
            if qr.get_module(x, y):  # If the module is black
                draw.rectangle(
                    [
                        ((x + border) * scale, (y + border) * scale),
                        ((x + border + 1) * scale - 1, (y + border + 1) * scale - 1)
                    ],
                    fill=0
                )

    return img

# Create a QR Code instance with specific settings
qr = qrcodegen.QrCode.encode_segments(
    [
        qrcodegen.QrSegment.make_bytes(b"https://www.parfois.com/view/"),  # Segment 1: URL (Byte mode)
        qrcodegen.QrSegment.make_numeric("224646"),  # Segment 2: Number (Numeric mode)
        qrcodegen.QrSegment.make_bytes(b"_BNM"),  # Segment 3: Suffix (Byte mode)
    ],
    ecl=qrcodegen.QrCode.Ecc.LOW,  # Error correction level LOW
    minversion=3,  # Force Version 3 (29x29)
    maxversion=3,  # Also Version 3 (29x29)
    mask=0  # Mask Pattern 0
)

# Generate the QR code image
img = generate_qr_image(qr, scale=10, border=4)

# Save the image as PNG
img.save("custom_qrcode.png")

Here is the decode of the image:


Thank you, but there are still some differences in the top left part; it’s not exactly the same.

Yes. You are correct. Your original image and the one I generated are different, even though they are equivalent in terms of the final decoded string. This is probably because they are not generated by the same algorithm.

Is it possible to determine which algorithm was used from just a QR code? If so, how?

I couldn't find anything on that. You must have a very good reason why the images must be identical.

A friend who makes hang tags asked me for that. I want to make sure I try everything before I tell him I can't do it.
